# What is value of msg.sender when reading contract on etherscan or bscscan?

Tags: etherscan, msg.sender, bscscan

When I look at a contract on etherscan or bscscan, it is possible to read the contract, which basically just calls a public function of the contract. But what value is used for msg.sender when I read a contract through the etherscan or bscscan web interface?

Answer (score 0):

This question is actually a bit broader one.

You always use some node to access the blockchain. And to interact with contracts, you need a wallet (a pair of private + public key).

Furthermore, there are two general ways to interact with contracts: static local reads and real transactions. Local reads only issue a local read to the node you are connected to, querying data. They can't modify contract state (except temporarily), since those are not broadcast to the network at all, and they are free of charge. Real transactions cost gas (Ethers) and are broadcast to the entire network. These can alter the state, and they need to be mined before they are valid.

When you issue a read from Etherscan (or similar), it issues a local read to the node it is connected to. That node has a wallet attached to it. So, for a local call, the `msg.sender` is the address of the wallet. For a real transaction, you need to connect your own wallet, so the `msg.sender` is you.

You can test this with a contract which has only one function:

```
function test() public view returns(address) {
    return msg.sender;
}
```

Comment: Well, the issue is that there is an existing contract on bscscan that has a function getInfo() that returns the value stored in a table indexed by msg.sender: return sometable[msg.sender]; I'm not sure why it is returning something other than 0.